# Como hacer que se ejecute la vista que le estoy cargando en el controlador

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Tengo esta función en mi vista

```
 $.ajax({<br>
     type: "POST",            
     url: url, <br>
     data: {id: id}, 
})
```

Donde `url` contiene una dirección al controlado estoy utilizando `Codeigniter` ahora en el controlador tengo

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
   $data['datos'] = $this->input->post('id');
   $this->load->view('add_cliente_view',$data);
}
```

El código se ejecuta correctamente (lo veo en el `Firebug`) pero no cambia a la vista que le estoy indicando.

Comment: Puede ser porque la petición es ajax

Answer (score 1):

Creo que buscas seguridad enviando por post el ID, te muestro 3 formas de hacer lo que quieres (2 con get y 1 con post):

1ra con get) en vez de $.ajax uses:

```
window.location.href = url + id;
// donde url sería: la url base + "controlador/add_cliente_view/id"
```

2da con get) cambies en el controlador

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
{
   $id = $this->input->post('id');
   redirect('controlador/add_cliente_view/'.$id); // por url
}
```

3ra) al querer llegar a una url con post, debes simular un submit

```
// Esta función en javascript te ayudará a llegar a una url con POST simulado.
function post(url, parametros) { // parametros es json
    var form = $('<form></form>');

    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("action", url);

    $.each(parametros, function(clave, valor) {
        var campo = $('<input></input>');

        campo.attr("type", "hidden");
        campo.attr("name", clave);
        campo.attr("value", valor);

        form.append(campo);
    });

    $(document.body).append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

y para ejecutar la función en javascript escribes:

```
post(url + 'controlador/add_cliente_view', {id: id});
// url sería base_url(), no sé que tienes en url
```

por último a donde llegaste con tu problema te serviría para en un div de tu misma página puedas cargar el formulario, pero como necesitas cambiar de url serían estas 3 formas

```
$.ajax({<br>
    type: "POST",            
    url: url, <br>
    data: {id: id}, 
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#nombre_div').html(data);
});
```

Nos vemos